# bash for loop running more than the length of array

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash 
arrck=
arrrlt=

if true; then
arrck+=("1")
arrrlt+=("one")
else
    echo "something"
fi 

for i in ${!arrck[*]} 
do
    echo "${arrck[i]} is ${arrrlt[i]}"
done


output 1-- 

 is
1 is one

output 2--tracing on  

 ./Building_block.sh
+ arrck=
+ arrrlt=
+ true
+ arrck+=("1")
+ arrrlt+=("one")
+ for i in '${!arrck[*]}'
+ echo ' is '
 is
+ for i in '${!arrck[*]}'
+ echo '1 is one'
1 is one
```

Why is the loop running with no value assigned to i ? i can say it tried to execute echo "${arrck[]} is ${arrrlt[]}" and picking the blank space as value.

Comment: after commenting the declaration, it is running as expected just 1 time( length of the array) 
```
arrck=
arrrlt=
```

Comment: There are 2 cells/elements in the array: `echo ${!arrck[@]}` ==> `0 1`

Comment: arrck=()
arrrlt=()  , also sloved the issue.

Comment: The first two lines of the script don't do anything useful.

Comment: @chepner but they do create an initial cell with index `0` for the 2 arrays `arrck` and `arrrlt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a value to a variable you are actually assigning a value to cell/position `0` in an array, eg:

```
$ x=5

$ echo ${x}
5

$ echo ${!x[@]}
0

$ echo ${x[0]}
5

$ echo ${x[@]}
5
```

In your example the first set of commands assign the empty string to index position '0' of the 2 arrays `arrck[]` and `arrrlt[]`:

```
$ arrck=
$ arrrlt=

$ echo "${!arrck[@]} : ${!arrrlt[@]}"
0 : 0
```

The `if/then/else` block then appends a second set of values to your arrays with indexes `1` and values of `1` and `one`.

The `for` loop then loops through the 2 available indices for the `arrck[]` array, namely `0` and `1`.

What you probably want to do is start out by dropping/deallocating your arrays (as opposed to creating cell `0`), eg:

```
$ unset arrck
$ unset arrrlt
$ echo "${!arrck[@]:-undefined} : ${!arrrlt[@]:-undefined}"
undefined : undefined
```